# Bidirectional links in file systems?

Tags: operating-systems, filesystems

Typcial links are unidirectional, which has the drawback that the link
will point to invalid if its target is moved or deleted.
Bidirectional links would provide the possibility to update.
Moreover: If the target of a link is a location (folder etc.)
a bidirectional link would allow to show the "back-link" at the target location too,
with its own name perhaps.

My question:
Is there a way to use bidirectional links?
Is this concept realized somehow already?
How could it be realized?
(I'm at NTFS, Windows)